# SQL: Filter Results When 0, Except When Column X is not null

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Likely missing something really obvious, but I'm trying to filter the results of my query in GBQ. In the example below, I'd like to filter out results where `invamt` is null. However, I want to keep any results where `invamt` is 0, but `order amt` is not 0

```
DATA
  csr | inv amt| order amt  |  
-----------------------------
 bob  |  12,00 |     0      |
 bil  |   0    |     0      |
 art  |   0    |     0      |
 tia  |   0    |     12     |

OUTPUT
  csr | inv amt| order amt  |  
-----------------------------
 bob  |  12,00 |     0      |
 tia  |   0    |     12     |
```

I've attempted
`where invamt <> 0 and not (invamt = 0 and orderamt > 0)`  but doesn't seem to be giving me the correct results. Any ideas?

Edit: apologies -- used NULL and 0 results interchangeably. Definitely not the same thing

Comment: You have no `null` values in your sample data.

Comment: Your edit acknowledges your mistake. But you still need to correct your question. In its current state it's self contradictory.

Comment: Yep -- accidentally used null and 0 interchangeably. Glad most were able to make out my actual question by context though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BigQuery Standard SQL

Assuming (from the context of question and fields name) that you are not dealing with negative numbers and actual NULLS, but rather zero and positive numbers only:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *
FROM `project.dataset.data`
WHERE inv_amt + order_amt > 0
```

if to apply to sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.data` AS (
  SELECT 'bob' csr, 12.00 inv_amt, 0 order_amt UNION ALL
  SELECT 'bil', 0, 0 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'art', 0, 0 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'tia', 0, 12 
)
SELECT *
FROM `project.dataset.data`
WHERE inv_amt + order_amt > 0
```

output is

```
Row csr     inv_amt     order_amt    
1   bob     12.0        0    
2   tia     0.0         12
```

Another [below] option is just for fun and learning [hopefully for you] experience

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *
FROM `project.dataset.data`
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(FORMAT('%t', STRUCT(inv_amt, order_amt)), r'[123456789]')
```

Comment: Much appreciated! Yea, I was looking to include 0 data (not null data). Appreciate the response and solution on this

Answer (score 0):

Based on your sample data, you seem to simply want:

```
where invamt <> 0 or orderamt <> 0
```

Based on your question:

> I'd like to filter out results where invamt is null. However, I want to keep any results where invamt is null, but order amt is not null

you seem to want:

```
where invamt is not null or orderamt is not null
```

If both `NULL`s and `0` are possible, then this should be sufficient:

```
where invamt <> 0 or orderamt <> 0
```

This guarantees that one of the columns has a non-`NULL`, non-`0` value.